# How can I use Spring XML configuration to set a bean property with list of all beans of a certain type?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following XML configuration:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="Simple"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="Simple"/>

<bean id="tasks" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="bean1" />
            <ref bean="bean2" />                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="list" class="Comp">
    <property name="tasks" ref="tasks"/>
</bean>
```

The "tasks" contains all beans of type Simple. The problem with this is that I might forget to add a Simple bean I've configured to the list.

I could do this programatically using

```
Map map = context.getBeansOfType(Simple.class);
```

and setting the list bean with the beans retrieved.

Is there any way of doing this using just XML configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your context file should like this:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="Simple"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="Simple"/>

<bean id="list" class="Comp" autowire="byType"/>
```

Note the `autowire="byType"` addition, and [the autowiring documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire).

Comment: Wouldn't this just put the list itself in the Comp's tasks property? How does this help populating the list itself with all beans of type Simple?

Comment: @rudolfson: the list should not exist anymore, and the javadoc for @Autowired has a nice explanation of the rules: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. I didn't read the autowire docs to the end and so wasn't aware of this capability. +1 for you answer!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest writing your own `FactoryBean` for creating such a list. This would be reusable and then configurable using XML only. The `FactoryBean` would look like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class CollectingListFactoryBean implements FactoryBean, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext appCtx;
    private Class type;

    public Object getObject() {
        Assert.notNull(type, "type must be initialized");
        List result = new ArrayList();
        result.addAll(appCtx.getBeansOfType(type).values());
        return result;
    }

    public Class getObjectType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.appCtx = applicationContext;
    }

    public void setType(Class type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Then your XML configuration would be

```
<bean id="bean1" class="Simple"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="Simple"/>

<bean id="tasks" class="CollectingListFactoryBean">
    <property name="type" value="Simple" />
</bean>

<bean id="list" class="Comp">
    <property name="tasks" ref="tasks"/>
</bean>
```

NOTE: I didn't have the time to test the example above. I just used code I already had as a template. ;) Especially I'm not sure if passing `Simple` as a `Class` argument for the `type` property works this way. Just give it a try. In the worst case you would have to use `String` as the property type and use `Class.forName(type)` to get your class. But my guess is that Spring does this transformation for you.

**EDIT** Even though this solution should work, I recommend Robert Munteanu's answer.